# Meteor dynamic category list

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I would like to do the following. I would like to create a categories page that loads each category onto a picture. Then when a user clicks a category the parameter would show up on the url and it will search the database for photos based on that category. I will now demonstrate the code that I have.

**Categories HTML File:**

```
<template name="categories">
    <div class="text-center light-container" id="categories-section">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <hr/>
        {{#each categories}}
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="{{pathFor route='categoryPage'}}">
                    <img class="freezeframe pics" src="images/app/sphere.jpg"/>
                </a>
                <h2><span>{{categories}}</span></h2>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**Categories JS File:**

```
var categoryList = ['actions', 'animals', 'anime', 'art/design', 'cartoons/comics', 'celebrities',
 'Emotions', 'Food/Drink', 'Games', 'History', 'Holidays', 'Memes', 'Movies', 'Music', 'Nature', 'News/Politics',
 'Science', 'Sports', 'Technology', 'TV'];

Template.categories.helpers({
    'categories':function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++){
            console.log(categoryList[i]);
            return categoryList[i];
        }
    }
});
```

**Router JS File:**

```
Router.route('/categories', {
    name: 'categories',
    template: 'categories',
    fastRender: true
});
Router.route('/categories/:category', {
    name: 'categoryPage',
    template: 'categoryPage',
    data: function(){
        var category = this.params.category;
        return GifsCollection.find({category: category});
    },
    fastRender: true
});
```

**CategoryPage JS:**

```
Template.categoryPage.helpers({
    // Load 16 most recent ones
    // When down arrow is click load another 16 more gifs
    gifs: function() {
        var category = this.params.category;
        return GifsCollection.find({category: category}, {fields: {_id: 1, image: 1} });
    }
});
```

Running the following code doesn't get me anywhere. I'm not sure which path to take. I can create a 'category' collection and load the helpers onto there or I can use sessions? but I'm leaning onto creating category collection however I'm pretty sure there is a much more efficient way.

Any feedback and code help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: what that `return` supposed to do in the categories helper? This will simply return `categoryList[0]`. I think you want to replace that for loop with just `return categoryList;`.

Comment: also, it's not quite clear what you are asking. Is this code not working? are you looking for help debugging? is this just about getting advice on the code design?

Comment: Hey @ChristianFritz thanks for replying. Basically what I'm trying to do is load the variable 'categoryList' onto each picture. So one picture will have the title 'action' the next 'adventure' and so on.

I did what you have said returned the categoryList only and it worked but it's loading the whole list for each picture.

Comment: okay nvm i have solved it. I changed my array to a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two small errors. One we already discussed in comments, regarding the helper. The other is in how you use the `#each` loop: inside of it you can just refer to `this` to get the string of your category.

Categories HTML File:

```
<template name="categories">
    <div class="text-center light-container" id="categories-section">
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <hr/>
        {{#each categories}}
            <div class="image-container">
                <a href="/categories/{{this}}">
                    <img class="freezeframe pics" src="images/app/sphere.jpg"/>
                </a>
                <h2><span>{{this}}</span></h2>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Categories JS File:

```
var categoryList = ['actions', 'animals', 'anime', 'art/design', 'cartoons/comics', 'celebrities',
 'Emotions', 'Food/Drink', 'Games', 'History', 'Holidays', 'Memes', 'Movies', 'Music', 'Nature', 'News/Politics',
 'Science', 'Sports', 'Technology', 'TV'];

Template.categories.helpers({
    'categories':function(){
        return categoryList;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man this is much better than the json object i implemented. I now however run into another problem. I'm trying to pass data using iron router. I want to get the category name onto the url and when user lands on category page the respective photos from that category will load.

I will post a link with all of the code I have for the page 'categoryPage'.

Comment: Here is the new link to the problem I'm currently facing.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911969/loading-data-using-iron-router-and-meteor